# How can I compute the derivative of a function of 't' mapped to another function that has a function within it but no actual 't' variables?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I won't give the exact example but let's say I have this function $G: t ↦ F(Y(t))$

I know this to translate to $G(t) = F(Y(t))$

If $F(y)$ is some complicated equation with constants $a, b$, such as $y^3 - (a+b)/y^2 +a\log(|a+b+y|)$

and a function $Y'(t) = Y(t)/Y(t)(a+bY(t))$

Then how can I bring this all together to compute by hand a derivative for $G(t) = F(Y(t))$?

I think I first need to plug $Y(t)$ into the $y$ values of $F(y)$ like $Y(t)^3 - (a+b)/Y(t)^2 + a\log(|a+b+Y(t)|)$

That's about all I can figure out. Because I have $Y'(t)$ but not $Y(t)$. and I'm not sure how i can get $G'(t)$ when I don't have actual $t$ variables in any equation

Comment: I think you need to figure out what $Y(t)$ might be. I'm a little confused by your equation for $Y'(t)$, because $Y(t)/Y(t) = 1$ (as long as $Y(t)\neq0$) so that seems like unnecessary clutter. But it looks like you have some sort of ordinary differential equation (ODE) for $Y(t)$. There are ways to solve some of these, but no general way to solve every ODE, so it matters exactly which one you actually have.

Comment: You use the Chain Rule, of course: $$G'(t) = F'(Y(t))Y'(t)$$

Comment: Oh my god. I am the world's biggest dunce. Thank you kind sir. I just answered the question in 2 seconds. My brain always tries to think every problem must be really complicated -.-